reform AWS pre-signed URL with query parameters as a header-based authorization
I have a presigned URL for a get request like:
https://<my-bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<path/to/file.dat>?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=<credential-string>%2F20241107%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20241107T202532Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=<signature-string>

I want to use httr2 caching, so I want to reformulate this URL using the header-based authorization so that the cache doesn't get invalidated just because the date and credentials change. However, I can't get the header-based request working. Here's what I'm trying, based on this documentation:
aws_authorization = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256Credential=<credential-string>%2F20241107%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date=20241107T202532Z;x-amz-expires=900,Signature=<signature-string>"

For clarity, here's the Authorization header again with line breaks:
aws_authorization = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
Credential=<credential-string>%2F20241107%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request,
SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date=20241107T202532Z;x-amz-expires=900,
Signature=<signature-string>"

I then reconstruct the request as
req = request("https://<my-bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<path/to/file.dat>") |>
  req_headers(Authorization = aws_authorization)

req
#> <httr2_request>
#> GET
#> https://<my-bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<path/to/file.dat>
#> Headers:
#> • Authorization:
#> 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256Credential=<credential-string>/20241107/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date=20241107T202532Z;x-amz-expires=900,Signature=<signature-string>'
#> Body: empty

But I get a HTTP 400 Bad Request error when I perform the request:
req_perform(req)
#> HTTP 400 Bad Request.

Where am I going wrong in constructing the request?
EDIT
Modified based on comments:

remove x-amz-expires from SignedHeaders.
Remove = from SignedHeaders, and define referenced headers.

So Now my Authorization string is
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256Credential=<credential-string>%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date,Signature=<signature-string>

And I have added headers
X-Amz-Date = 20241107T202532Z
X-Amz-Expires = 900

Resulting in the request
#> <httr2_request>
#> GET
#> <my-bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<path/to/file.dat>
#> Headers:
#> • Authorization:
#> 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256Credential=<credential-string>%2F20241107%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date,Signature=<signature-string>'
#> • X-Amz-Date: '20241107T220527Z'
#> • X-Amz-Expires: '900'
#> Body: empty


I believe x-amz-expires only applies to query string authorization and is not required for header based authorization. Look at this related question.

Thanks @MichaelLogothetis, but omitting the x-amz-expires component still yields HTTP 400 Bad Request

SignedHeaders should only be the list of headers used, such as:
SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date
with no ';' after the last header listed.

@MichaelLogothetis see my edit, I understand what you are saying but I must still have an error.

I’ve written two versions - one using Python requests and one using R httr2. Both seem to be making the same request and sending the same headers. The Python version works the httr2 version returns a 400. I suspect the problem is how I have structured the headers in httr2.

Thanks @MichaelLogothetis, I'd be interested in seeing your python solution and attempted R solution. Feel free to submit as an answer, I think your python solution is important as it demonstrates it can be done.

The following was done using:

R version 4.4.2 (2024-10-31)
httr2 package version 1.0.6.9000
macOS Sonoma 14.6.1

httr2 1.0.6 includes a function req_auth_aws_v4() that gets close to what you want but I couldn't get it to work with AWS s3. However, the req_auth_aws_v4() code is useful if you want to create your own signing algorithm.
AWS provides helpful debug information in its responses to unsuccessful signing requests. If you are seeing a 400 Bad Request response, I would try the following to stop httr2 throwing an error, so you can see the response content:
req = request("https://<my-bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<path/to/file.dat>") |> req_headers(Authorization = aws_authorization)
    
req <- req_verbose(
  req,
  header_req = TRUE,
  header_resp = TRUE,
  body_req = TRUE,
  body_resp = TRUE,
  info = TRUE,
  redact_headers = FALSE
)

tryCatch(
  resp <- req |> req_perform(),
  httr2_http_400 = function(cnd) {
   last_response() |> resp_raw()
  }

I wrote (borrowed) the following code using Python requests that successfully returns an AWS S3 object using header authentication:
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac
import requests
method = 'GET'
service = 's3'
host = '<my-bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-east-1'
endpoint = 'https://<my-bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com'
request_parameters = ''

def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning

access_key = "AABBCCDDEEFF11223344"
secret_key = "SomeBigLongSecretKeyToUseForAWSDontShare"

if access_key is None or secret_key is None:
    print('No access key is available.')
    sys.exit()

t = datetime.datetime()
amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d') # Date w/o time, used in credential scope

canonical_uri = '/<path/to/file.dat>'
canonical_querystring = request_parameters
canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD' + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + '\n'
signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date'
payload_hash = 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD'
canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash
algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'

print(canonical_request)

string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service)
signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

print(signature)

authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature
headers = {'x-amz-date':amzdate, 'x-amz-content-sha256': 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD', 'Authorization':authorization_header}
request_url = endpoint + canonical_uri

print(authorization_header)
print('\nBEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
print('Request URL = ' + request_url)

r = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers)

print('\nRESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
print('Response code: %d\n' % r.status_code)
print(r.text)

The important things to note here are that it sends the following headers:

x-amz-date
x-amz-content-sha256
Authorization

and that the Authorization header is formatted as:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AABBCCDDEEFF11223344/20241110/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,Signature=2ad745df5f4680d42800865d775ca045651eb42819e18592b99c43c3c00b949f

Note the space ' ' separator between the algorithm and Credential:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential

The httr2 req_auth_aws_v4() function appears to generate an Authorization header that has a ',' between the algorithm and Credential that may be the problem:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256,Credential

If you have a valid signature, the following headers seem to work using httr2:
library(httr2)

aws_date = "20241110"
aws_time = "170747"
sig = "64aa96f4dceaa3b782245ba9a070621190e1feab93c349bc6a5a83a8ce8ee4e3"

# Tested with AWS S3
#
# The Authorization header for AWSV4 appears to require a space " " after the Algorithm AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
#

aws_authorization = paste("AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AABBCCDDEEFF11223344/", aws_date, "/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,Signature=", sig, sep = "")

req <- request("https://<my-bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com")
req <- req |> req_url_path(path = "<path/to/file.dat")
req <- req |> req_headers("Authorization" = aws_authorization, "host" = "<my-bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com", "x-amz-content-sha256" = "UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD", "x-amz-date" = paste(aws_date,"T",aws_time,"Z", sep = ""))

req <- req_verbose(
  req,
  header_req = TRUE,
  header_resp = TRUE,
  body_req = TRUE,
  body_resp = TRUE,
  info = TRUE,
  redact_headers = FALSE
)

req

tryCatch(
  resp <- req |> req_perform(),
  httr2_http_400 = function(cnd) {
   last_response() |> resp_raw()
  }
)

resp |> resp_body_raw()

Hopefully, with some changes to the httr2 req_auth_aws_v4() function this can be simplified to the following in the future.
library(httr2)

req <- request("https:/<my-bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<path/to/file.dat>")

req <- req_auth_aws_v4(
  req,
  aws_access_key_id = "AABBCCDDEEFF11223344",
  aws_secret_access_key = "SomeBigLongSecretKeyToUseForAWSDontShare",
  aws_service = "s3",
  aws_region = "us-east-1"
)

resp <- req_perform(req)

resp


Thanks, this has gotten me from 400 bad request to 403 forbidden, and with req_verbose() I see a message that the signatures don't match. This tells me that my request is now formatted correctly, but I need to look into how my AWS administrator is constructing the presigned URLs.
